# RSS feed for new Stack Exchanges

Tags: feature-request, area-51, feed

I'd like to subscribe to a feed of all Stack Exchange sites that reach 'beta' status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing just happens to exist!

I created a small application called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that converts API requests into RSS feeds.

The one that does what you're looking for is:

http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackauth/sites

Comment: Looks great! I think the meta sites should not be in the feed though.

Comment: Appears to not include public betas. I don't see anywhere near the 65 SE sites I've created accounts on.

Comment: @dgw: Actually, the application has been moved [here](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com). You will also need to manually override the API version to see all of the sites, so you'll need to append `'?api_version=1.0'` to the URL.

Comment: @George Edison: Aha, there it is. That's what it's supposed to do. Thanks! Added to my Google Reader. :)